# What is the purpose of $ in the following example code?

Tags: php

Does it create a variable that can be used later? Such as `int a;` in C++? I am new to programming in HTML and I am currently programming a website and most of the tutorials. I have watched failed to explain to me what the purpose of $ is while defining PHP variable values.

```
    <?php 
        $sitename="Every Moments Studio"; 
        $sitedescription="Because every picture tells a story,let me help you tell yours"
       $sitepath="http://people.oregonstate.edu/~atkurua";
       $author="jason";
     ?>
```

Comment: end where is the "example of code"???

Comment: I have just posted it! Sorry I am new to this site, had to learn how to trigger the code

Comment: Yup. A variable always starts with a `$` sign, followed by the name of the variable. Refer [Diving into php](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/diving-into-php--net-3590).

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell from the **php** tag the code is in, this is not **HTML**, its **PhP**

In **PhP** variables have to be initialized and declared with a **"$"** (Dollar) character.

I would send you a link to learn more about this, but that's basically it.
If you are new to HTML, you will eventually get to PhP another time. And when you are there you surely will get it.